# mysql_real_escape_string leaves slashes

Tags: javascript, php, url-encoding

I am using post method to send data. And the data is an array so I just use `encodeURIComponent` before it is send.

POST data:

```
    data = "data="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data));
```

And in the receiving page:

```
    $data =  json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

In the `for` loop I used `mysql_real_escape_string`

```
    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
    {
        $data[$i] = trim(mysql_real_escape_string($data[$i]));
    }
```

The problem is this method causes a slash in the data which is saved to database. Help me to remove the slash automatically added. (Sometimes data may contain a slash which cannot be removed.)

Comment: Dont use encodeUriComponent. Only post-modify the data on the server using PHP, because its still possible for a harmful person to bypass javascript code making the encoding useless. Use JavaScript for any optical stuff, input helpers, focus inputs and such but avoid using it for security as it will break immediately if only one average skilled person attempts to mess with your website.

Comment: The extra slashes might come from `magic_quotes`. Google that first and check if they are turned on

Comment: if i turn magic_quotes off is there any security issue

Comment: i use php.ini file to turn off magic_quotes, then restarted apache. but still the problem

Comment: Verify the value of `data` and `$data` at every point to find out where the slashes are added. Also, consider using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the original MySQL API.

Comment: Wouldn't `preg_replace("/\\|\//", "", $data[$i])` give you your desired result?

Comment: I think encodeURIComponent() is escaping JSON strings \' however I'm sure they are URI safe

Comment: Did you modify the right `php.ini`? Sometimes there are multiple spread across the system.

Comment: i got the answer. i will update the same as answer. thanks for response.